# Is Facebook deleting Facebook Pages for criticizing the police?

Tags: united-states, facebook, censorship

According to [WSWS.org,](http://www.wsws.org/en/articles/2018/10/15/pers-o15.html)

> The banned pages include highly popular postings by groups **opposing and publicizing incidents of police violence** such as Police the Police, Cop Block and Filming Cops [...]

[RT also seems to corroborate that (but it's likely that this is WSWS's source)](https://www.rt.com/usa/441075-facebook-twitter-banned-accounts/). RT also lists "Cop Logic" a site that highlights and documents *“the absurd and unpredictable antics of cops”* across the globe was deleted?

Comment: Is the the claim that they deleted pages *for* criticizing police, as per your title, or that they deleted pages that simply happened to be criticizing the police, which is what the quote seems to suggest.

Comment: There is no way to confirm the actual reasoning for Facebook's deletions. We only have their (extremely hypocritical) proclaimed reasoning that the pages were publishing "sensational political content."

Comment: Are you asking "Were Police the Police/Cop Block/Filming Cops/Cop Logic banned by Facebook?"  That seems a reasonable question, although perhaps hard to answer. Are you asking "Did Facebook ban them for opposing and publicizing incidents of police violence, despite Facebook giving different reasons (i.e. inauthentic behaviour)?" That is a motivation question that is pretty much impossible to answer, and is off-topic.